# Shopify - Add MP4 video to the Collection/Video block

Tags: html, css, video, shopify

I'm editing one of the base template offered by shopify.

I basically have an MP4 file on my computer and I would like to use it as VIDEO block on one of the Collection section's blocks.

Unfortunately the only option I have is uploading it on youtube or vimeo and then copy the url.
Is there any ways to avoid that and just upload my mp4 file? Or even better, I already have my mp4 uploaded on my database (FTP) so even a way to run my custom url instead.

Something like I type: "www.randomwebsite.co.uk/video_url.mp4" on the URL box and it automatically embed it as  .

I'm friendly with some coding but I can't figure out on how to customize it from the shopify template.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! do you want multiple video blocks or just 1 video section

Comment: Need to upload the files using the backend files section and copy and use URL to save into block.